# An app or script to watch folder and display new images in full screen?

Tags: graphics, script, tethering

I'm teaching a photography class and would like to use a cheap setup to display photos taken by the students in real time.

I have a macbook pro and an iphone. I also have an eye-fi card but it's an old one and doesn't work with ad-hoc networks so that's out of the question.

I'll likely be using RemoteSnap on the iphone connected to an ad-hoc wi-fi created by the mac. With this setup, the photo jpgs end up in a folder.

How can I haev every new photo in this folder to appear on the screen (in full screen)?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you on Lion or Snow Leopard? (Or another Mac OS X version?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hopefully this should work regardless of OS version, but it's been tested on 10.6.8:

1. Open Automator
2. Choose to create a Folder Action
3. Choose your photo folder as the folder to work on
4. Chooses Utilities -> Run AppleScript and drag it into the panel on the right 
   [image: Automator]
5. Paste the code below into the Run AppleScript panel
6. Save the folder action and try it out!

`on run {input, parameters}`

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the_folder to container of (item 1 of input) as alias

    if window 1 exists then
        set the target of window 1 to the_folder
    else
        reveal the_folder
    end if

    --Send the Esc key to exit the previous quick-look, if there is one
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 53
    end tell

    delay (1)

    --select the new file
    select input as alias
    activate
    activate window 1

    delay (1)

    --Activate full screen quick look on the selected file
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "y" using {command down, option down}
    end tell
end tell

return input
```

end run

**Note**: The script might have some unnecessary elements in it, but while trying to tweak it it often stopped working. Feel free to try on your own!

Comment: Thank you for this. The workshop was yesterday and I ended up installing a Lightroom trial and used its watch folder option. I will definitely try the script as a lightweight solution next time I'm doing this.

Answer (score 1):

The other simpler alternative is to accept that you are already in fullscreen quicklook mode, and use the following Applescript in the above Automator action to simply select the newest file.

```
tell application "Finder"
    set the_folder to container of (item 1 of input) as alias

    if window 1 exists then
        set the target of window 1 to the_folder
    else
        reveal the_folder
    end if

    select input as alias
    activate
    activate window 1
end tell
```

If you are already within a fullscreen quicklook, then effectively you are showing the newest file screen. It is akin to pressing "up" or "down" while in fullscreen quicklook on an already populated directory.

Take your first picture, enter fullscreen quicklook mode, take successive pictures.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there's no good (free) way of doing this.

I tried the above script, but unfortunately, with 10.8, if you are in full screen already, the next image DEACTIVATES full screen (as it sends <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>y</kbd>).  There's no way of seeing the current "state" and if it should just select the new file or select the new file and full screen it. :(

However, I wrote a Quartz Composer Screen Saver to auto-update and rotate over the last X number of images.

https://github.com/jnovack/slideshow/